# Cookie doesn't getting saved in Nextjs using cookies-next

Tags: next.js, cookies, setcookie

I'm currently trying to set a cookie with key `'token'` as:

```js
import { setCookie } from "cookies-next";

export const setToken = (token = '') => {
    setCookie("token", token, { maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 100 });
};
```

I checked until yesterday, and this 'token' cookie was being saved in the browser, but when I tried to access the website today, I discovered that the cookie was not being saved, no matter how many times I tried, and even I had not made any modifications.

I'm using

```
"next": "13.5.4",
"react": "^18",
"react-dom": "^18",
"cookies-next": "^4.1.1",
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the 'token' was exceeded the size limit of Cookie.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).